# Two chained invocations among several async invocations

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous

I have a method in my Kotlin app that looks like this:

```
coroutineScope{
      val aFetcher = async { a.fetch()}
      val bFetcher = async { b.fetch()}
      val cFetcher = async { c.fetch()}
      val dFetcher = async { d.fetch()}

      Merged(a.await(),b.await(),c.await(),d.await())
}
```

The problem I am having is that I can't find a way to make one request depend on the other. In my case, I need for cFetcher to wait until bFetcher ended it's work before starting.

What's the right way to do that in Kotlin?

Comment: is it just me, or does that just seems like syncronous code with extra steps? Why have them async if they need to wait for each other anyway?

Comment: Not all steps are required to wait for each other. I have a good bunch that does not.

Comment: then remove the async _only_ from the steps previous to the ones that need to wait. If `c` needs to wait for `b`, there is no point for `b` to be async.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make the part that should be synchronous, synchronous.

```
coroutineScope{
      val aFetcher = async { a.fetch() }
      val dFetcher = async { d.fetch() }
      val bResult = b.fetch()
      val cFetcher = async { c.fetch(bResult) }

      Merged(aFetcher.await(), bResult, cFetcher.await(), dFetcher.await())
}
```

If you have more than one of these dependencies and want to run them in parallel you could do something like this I suppose:

```
coroutineScope{
      val aFetcher = async { a.fetch() }
      val dFetcher = async { d.fetch() }
      val bAndCFetcher = async {
        val bResult = b.fetch()
        bResult to c.fetch(bResult) 
      }

      Merged(aFetcher.await(), bAndCFetcher.await().first, bAndCFetcher.await().second, dFetcher.await())
}
```